# Using IdentityServer4 as Class Library instead of Hosting Solution

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I have been exploring IdentityServer4 for a couple of days. It performs hosting internally generating a connect/token endpoint which internally validates and generates an access token.
Even to call it a discovery URL is needed ultimately requiring a web app template for hosting.
Is it possible to use IdentityServer4 as a library that just allows access tokens to be generated?

**Updated Based on input from Bryan

What I am trying to achieve here is GSMA Compliance that requires both OpenID Connect and OAuth. I need to generate an Access Token as well as Identity_Token. But the caveat here is that IdentityServer4 hosts its internal endpoint where I do have custom endpoints. Also it require http based calling and I do require a sort of library that I can integrate and internally call to generate Access token as well as Identity Token.

** Some more update
We have hosted a custom GSMA compliant Web API Project and have hosted several endpoints as per required by GSMA ultimately validating and sanitizing the request landing on our endpoints. Internally we do require an Access token and Identity Token to be generated and shared back on the callback of the calling party.  Currently, I have used an Identity Server template which is MVC based project ultimately requiring us to use at least two ports/project one for our Custom GSMA compliant APIs and one for Identity Server. Calling identity server via URL add a new hop and an HTTP request needs to be sent out to Identity Server whereas I was thinking to use IdentityServer as a class library somewhat allowing me to pass in input parameter and do get an access token/ identity toke. 
Upon dissecting server Identity Server project like

```
Identity Server 4
Identity Mode
Identity Storage
```

I got the impression that it's very difficult to exact a library out of these projects that can help me generate access token/identity token easily.

Answer (score 3):

IdentityServer4 is an OpenID Connect (and OAuth) identity service -- it's not just about tokens.  Those technologies are primarily HTTP-based.  Thus IS4 is built on top of ASP.Net Core's web tech.  If you just need tokens (JWT, I assume), it's pretty simple to roll your own and use them however you see fit.  A few Google searches (or an SO search) will provide you with the code needed to create your own JWTs (for example: https://houseofcat.io/tutorials/csharp/identity/createjwt).  Without more information about how you want to use them, I can't elaborate on this answer.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan Lewis . What I am trying to achieve is GSMA Compliance that requires both OpenID connect and OAuth. I need to generate Access Token as well as Identity_Token. But the ceveat here is that Identity Server 4 hosts its internal endpoint where I do have custom endpoints.

Comment: @hellowahab, can you clarify what you mean by custom endpoints?  I am not familiar with GSMA Compliance. Do you want to change the existing "well-known" endpoints (discovery, auth, user, etc) or simply create new additional endpoints?  It's pretty trivial to add additional API endpoints on an existing IS4 server (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html)

Comment: We have already hosted a custom GSMA compliant Web API Project and have hosted several endpoints as per required by GSMA ultimately validating and sanitizing the request landing on our endpoints. Internally we do require an Access token and Identity Token to be generated and shared back on the callback of the calling party.  Currently, I have used an Identity Server template which is MVC based project ultimately requiring us to use at least two ports/project one for our Custom GSMA compliant APIs and one for Identity Server. Call identity server via URL add ...(continued in the question above)